# "Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process"

Tags: python, automation, cpanel, passenger

I am getting this error when I run the python App in Cpanel. Here is a code of the passenger file. Do I need to add anything else to the passenger file?

```
import imp
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))

wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/faheem.py')
application = wsgi.application
```

Comment: Did you solve it? (yes, 6 years ago...) That's the only post about it in the whole stackoverflow...

Comment: Facing the same issue but with Nodejs App. Have you found a solution?

Comment: This could be caused by having `restart.txt` or `always_restart.txt` in the {PassengerRoot}/tmp directory. When you remove those files does the message go away?

Answer (score -1):

**Try this.**

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Django_Project_Name")

application = get_wsgi_application()